# Would it be legitimate to ask a question as if a ASCII symbol exists or not or work around it

Tags: support, scope

I am looking for a ASCII symbol  "+" within a circle, but I am not able to find it.

[image]

First one in the picture.

Would it be okay to ask a question that if this ASCII symbol exists as I couldn't find it on Google.

I found this ⊗ but not with +

Comment: In what possible sense would that be ASCII? (I don't think that term means what you think it means.) But no, I don't think this would be a suitable Stack Overflow question.

Comment: You are likely looking for a Unicode character. Check out e.g. http://unicode-table.com/en (as Jon says, it's unlikely to be a good fit as a question on Stack Overflow)

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/List_of_useful_symbols

Comment: So, I was curious, and checked @Pekka웃's first link.  [It does exist](http://unicode-table.com/en/2295/).

Comment: @CustomizedName Sorry, but I'm very curious how you managed to find the ⊗ symbol while missing the ⊕, which is in the same range, right next to it even.

Comment: I'd start with a Google Image Search, myself.

Comment: I already searched, but call it my bad luck, i couldnot find it myself

Comment: How the hell would this be on topic?  What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: [⊕ at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2295/index.htm](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2295/index.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out, whether you're looking for an ASCII or Unicode symbol, both of these things are *trivially searchable*. The characters in each set are well-defined, and there are comprehensive tables available far and wide across the Internet.

For example, [here is an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) that came up as the first hit in a basic Google search. And Pekka's referred you to [a Unicode character reference](http://unicode-table.com/en) that is even itself searchable. There are countless others.

As such, I don't think this question would be a good fit for Stack Overflow. I don't mean to discourage basic questions, or even imply that I think anything "Googleable" should be off-topic—I don't. But I do think some basic research is a reasonable expectation, and since the answer to this question would be found within the first few minutes…

Moreover, we want the questions and answers on Stack Overflow to be at least *somewhat* generally applicable. This question and its answers are not likely to be helpful to anyone else in the future. It is too specific, too difficult to search for, and anyone who wanted to know would already know which off-site references to consult to find the answer.

You *could* possibly get away with asking a more general question about how to find out if a particular symbol exists in the Unicode character set. Then you'd get answers like Pekka's, directing you to resources and suggesting search strategies that would be broadly applicable to anyone with a question of this nature. But you might get some resistance from the community, as it would appear you're simply asking a recommendation question, which we consider to be off-topic. My own feeling about this is mixed. It would be vaguely reminiscent of a recommendation question, but it is not the bad kind that we're trying to avoid. It would be asking about strategies to use in solving a problem, exactly the kind of reusable knowledge that we'd like to see accumulated here. Acceptance would likely depend on the precise wording of your question. Post a draft here on Meta and ask for feedback if you're interested in pursuing this route.